# R - How to convert decimal to MM:SS.XXX

Tags: r, duration

How do you convert SS.xxx (Seconds.Milliseconds) to MM:SS.xxx (Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds) using R?

For example, my input is

```
time = 92.180
```

my desired output is

```
time = 01:32.180
```

All time fields have 3 decimal places.

Comment: You can also use `lubridate::seconds_to_period(time)`

Comment: @RonakShah I tried that prior, however i am not a fan of the output "1M 32.18S"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is the lubridate package - since you did not specify the output class I included a few possible outputs:

```
package(lubridate)

t <- 92.180
# your output string as character
lubridate::seconds(t) %>% 
  lubridate::as_datetime() %>% 
  format("%M:%OS3") 

# output as period
lubridate::seconds(t) %>% 
  lubridate::as.period()

# output as duration
lubridate::seconds(t) %>% 
  lubridate::as.duration() 

# output as time time
lubridate::seconds(t) %>% 
  lubridate::as.difftime()
```